# Return the latest 10 records from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the link what I mean - 
i.stack.imgur.com/yYQbu.png.

Query from 2 columns name and version.(may only with one column I'll put version in name column).
So , Wheres matches name from title or post from same column name and returns all lowest number from version(column).

Can anyone give me example of some query?

So far I have this query:

```
   $name = substr($row[2],0,10);
   $q = mysql_query("SELECT name from films WHERE name LIKE '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the latest 10-20"? Is this a parameter? Or do you just want to skip the latest 9?

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Depends on what column you want to order on, if you have a date/timestamp or whatever.

Comment: I've rewrite question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your table has an `id` column as the primary key with auto increment.

In which case, you need to add an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to your query.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT name from films WHERE name LIKE '$name' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

`ORDER BY id DESC` will make your query put the latest records first.

`LIMIT 10` will ensure that you only grab 10 records.

Comment: Yes I have ID column with AI.You don't understand me what I mean.I don't know my query is right.I want to get * posts where matches name of post.For example: My post is - Skype 8.7.6 I need from query where returns all where matches Skype.

Comment: @yaman `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE name LIKE '%Skype%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Ok but I will have many other programs in name column.Can I get name from $GET ?

Comment: @yaman Yes. Just replace the word `Skype` with your variable. Keep the `%`.

Comment: thanks.How to get only 3 or more letters from $GET ? And if I have another column version how to combine name and version on query?

Comment: @yaman You can combine name and version with something like this.  `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE name LIKE '%Skype%' AND version='8.7.6' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`. As for limiting to 3 or more letters, you will have to ask a new question for that.

Comment: Limit will limit to 10 returns of query here maybe using substr to get first 3 characters from $GET and prints all posts where matches 3 of name from $GET ? Also how to get lowest number of 8.7.6 from version column?